# How to fetch and display primary key of an array that fetch from database in php

Tags: php

My query is like this:-

```
date = date('Y-m-d');
$ddate = date('Y-m',strtotime($date) + (24*3600*$add_days));
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id, end_date, lid, date_format(tbl_ldet.`start_date`, '%Y-%m') FROM tbl_ldet WHERE lid='".$id."'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {

                        $result_array[] =  $row[3];
                    }
    $people = $result_array;
    if (in_array($ddate, $people))
                        {
                            //echo '<pre>'; print_r($people); echo '</pre>'; 
                            $dcount++;

                        }
```

I got an array like this, which is fetched from database according to the above query,

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2017-12
    [1] => 2018-01
    [2] => 2018-02
)
```

The problem is, how can i able to fetch and display the primary key of the "tbl_ldet" from the array which i got

Thanks in advance

Comment: You already select id than why not display it in your array? check your table data first

Comment: You do set  `$result_array[] = $row[3]` in your code, so you only keep the third value in each line.  You could use $row[0] as the index of the array, and $row[3] as the value (associative array on $row[0]).

Comment: @Nic3500 means that you could use something like `$result_array[$row[0]] = $row[3]`

Comment: By the way, you could write all that code more elegant and simpler.